# How do I convert an escaped JSON string within a JSON object?

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm receiving a JSON object from a public API with a property that, itself, is an escaped JSON string.

```
{
   "responses":[
      {
         "info":"keep \"this\" in a string",
         "body":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Invalid command\",\"type\":\"Exception\",\"code\":123}}"
      },
      {
         "info":"more \"data\" to keep in a string",
         "body":"{\"error\":{\"message\":\"Other error\",\"type\":\"Exception\",\"code\":321}}"
      }
   ]
}
```

How do I convert this property into an actual JSON object (unescaped) in order to deserialize the entire response using NewtonSoft Json.NET?

Comment: Do you want to convert the body into JSON? Its already in JSON

Comment: I've tried deserialzing using Newtonsoft Json.NET, but I get errors when it tries to convert the body into a class.  `"Error converting value [JSON String] to type '[MyClass]'. Path 'responses[0].body', line 1, position 641."`

Comment: Check out my edit. I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the workable solution I used based off of [**Sam I am**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154123/1068128):

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var response in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)obj.responses)
{
    response.body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)response.body);
}
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Answer (score 4):

Your JSON contains a literal string for the `"body"` objects that is actually embedded, double-serialized JSON.  To deserialize this to a POCO hierarchy without needing to introduce an intermediate `string Json` surrogate property inside any of your types, you have a few options:

1. You could preprocess your JSON using [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) and replace the literal `"body"` strings with their parsed equivalents:

   ```
       var rootToken = JToken.Parse(json);
       foreach (var token in rootToken.SelectTokens("responses[*].body").ToList().Where(t => t.Type == JTokenType.String))
       {
           token.Replace(JToken.Parse((string)token));
       }

       var root = rootToken.ToObject<RootObject>();
   ```
2. You could introduce a generic `JsonConverter` for the POCO corresponding to each `Body` object that deserializes the incoming embedded JSON string literal as a string, then deserializes that string to the final POCO:

   ```
   public class EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T> : JsonConverter
   {
       public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
       {
           return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
       }

       public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
               return null;
           var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
           if (contract is JsonPrimitiveContract)
               throw new JsonSerializationException("Invalid type: " + objectType);
           if (existingValue == null)
               existingValue = contract.DefaultCreator();
           if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
           {
               var json = (string)JToken.Load(reader);
               using (var subReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)))
               {
                   // By populating a pre-allocated instance we avoid an infinite recursion in EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T>.ReadJson()
                   // Re-use the existing serializer to preserve settings.
                   serializer.Populate(subReader, existingValue);
               }
           }
           else
           {
               serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
           }
           return existingValue;
       }

       public override bool CanWrite { get { return false; } }

       public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
       {
           throw new NotImplementedException();
       }
   }
   ```

   Then use it like:

   ```
   var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json, new EmbeddedLiteralConverter<Body>());
   ```

   Or apply it to the property corresponding to `"body"` like so:

   ```
   public class Response
   {
       public string info { get; set; }
       [JsonConverter(typeof(EmbeddedLiteralConverter<Body>))]
       public Body body { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Note that the converter checks to see whether the incoming JSON token is a string, and if not, deserializes directly.  Thus the converter should be usable when the `"body"` JSON is and is not double-serialized.

For testing purposes I generated the following target classes using http://json2csharp.com/:

```
public class Error
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    public Error error { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public string info { get; set; }
    public Body body { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Response> responses { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To convert a json encoded as json string to Jobject, you can always use the technique below,

```
var token = JToken.Parse(text);
var json = JObject.Parse((string) token);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you can deserialize it into an intermediary class that has a property:  `string Body {get; set;}`
2. deserialize the "body" string into it's appropriate type
3. create a new instance of your a class that represents your destination model.
4. serialize that model

---

Here's a program that does it with the dynamic type and anonymous objects.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var json = File.ReadAllText("JsonFile1.json");
    dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

    var dest = new
    {
        responses = ((IEnumerable<dynamic>)obj.responses).Select(x => new
        {
            info = x.info,
            body = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)x.body)
        })
    };

    var destJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dest);
    File.WriteAllText("JsonFile2.json", destJson);
}
```

Alternatively, you can just construct a new version of whatever your destination type is instead of an anonymous type, if you don't feel like reserializing the josn.

Comment: @downvoter  Is my answer incorrect?  IS someone like the OP, who can already use JSON.Net, somehow unable to use my answer?

Comment: Looks like we both got downvoted.  I was hoping I find a way to clean up the JSON without making duplicate classes for all the different API responses (this is a simplified example of something much more complex) with something generic I can use to parse the values.