# How do I deserialize a property containing an escaped JSON string?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have an `application/json` response from an API that has a property, itself, containing an escaped JSON string.

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "aggregation_id": "533741f4-49da-4db9-9660-4ca7bafb30e1",
    "task_id": "217",
    "event_type": "discovery",
    "event_name": "device_discovery_complete",
    "method": "ssh",
    "message_details": "{\"aggregation_id\":\"533741f4-49da-4db9-9660-4ca7bafb30e1\",\"ou_id\":0,\"device_id\":13,\"node_id\":13,\"task_id\":217}",
    "time": "2018-01-25T17:59:25"
  }
```

I want to deserialize the object and the inner object to a model type.

```
public class Response
{
    public DateTime time {get; set;}
    public string event_name {get; set;}
    public string event_type {get; set;}
    public string method {get; set;}
    public MessageDetails message_details {get; set;}
}

public class MessageDetails
{
    public int device_id {get; set;}
}
```

Using a call like this

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>("... response string...");
```

However, Netwonsoft.Json handles the outer properties just fine, but throws an exception on matching `message_details`.

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value "... response string snipped ..." to type 'RpcApi.Entities.MessageDetails'. 
Path '[0].message_details', line 1, position 390. 
---> System.ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to RpcApi.Entities.MessageDetails.
```

Comment: have you tried removing the \ from the serialized json before converting?

Comment: I'm hoping to _avoid_ pre-processing the response string, if at all possible. If there's some way to _tell_ Newtonsoft.Json how to handle a nested JSON string.

Comment: Your problem is that `"message_details"` is actually serialized JSON embedded as a string.  If you can't fix the incoming JSON, you could use `EmbeddedLiteralConverter<MessageDetails>` from [C# - How can I convert escape string JSON values within a JSON object into literal JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154630/3744182).

Comment: *I'm hoping to avoid pre-processing*, well, you either do  pre-processing or post-processing. There is not other way. For post-processing, you make the `MessageDetails` a string, add another property like `MessageDetailsDeserialized`, deserialize the object, and then deserialize  `MessageDetails` to `MessageDetailsDeserialized`.

Comment: Aw, how is my question marked as a duplicate of a question with negative points?! I'm asking from the perspective of end-to-end type serialization, that other question is asking about sanitizing the input string _first_. Perspective matters!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a custom JsonConverter for this similar to this:

```
public class EmbeddedJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        return serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader((string)reader.Value), objectType);
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Mark the property with `[JsonConverter(typeof(EmbeddedJsonConverter))]` like:

```
public class Response
{
    public DateTime time { get; set; }
    public string event_name { get; set; }
    public string event_type { get; set; }
    public string method { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(EmbeddedJsonConverter))]
    public MessageDetails message_details { get; set; }
}
```

Then you will be able to deserialize with `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>()`.

The EmbeddedJsonConverter class extracts the json string from the object and then deserializes it. `CanConvert` should probably be made smarter for a truly generic use.