# How to escape especial characters in JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, escaping

I need to bind the JSON object to model classes. To achieve that I used following code lines.

My tested JSON as follows

```
{  
   "Message":null,
   "Error":false,
   "VData":{  
      "RNumber":null,
      "BRNumber":"Session1"
   },
   "onlineFields":{  
      "CCode":"Web",
      "MNumber":"15478655",
      "Product":"100",
      "JsonFile":{  
         "evaluation":{  
            "number":[  
               {  
                  "@paraID":"1000",
                  "@Value":"",
                  "@label":"We are america"
               },
               {  
                  "@paraID":"2000",
                  "@Value":"100",
                  "@label":"We are japan"
               },
               {  
                  "@paraID":"3000",
                  "@Value":"1000",
                  "@label":"We are UK"
               },
               {  
                  "@paraID":"4000",
                  "@Value":"",
                  "@label":"We are China"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

and this is my model classes.

```
public class VData
{
    public object RNumber { get; set; }
    public string BRNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Number
{
    [JsonProperty("@paraID")]
    public string paraID { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("@label")]
    public string label { get; set; }
}

public class Evaluation
{
    public List<Number> number { get; set; }
}

public class JsonFile
{
    public Evaluation evaluation { get; set; }
}

public class OnlineFields
{
    public string CCode { get; set; }
    public string MNumber { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    public JsonFile JsonFile { get; set; }
}

public class Response
{
    public object Message { get; set; }
    public bool Error { get; set; }
    public VData VData { get; set; }
    public OnlineFields onlineFields { get; set; }
}
```

To set the above JSON to my model, I used the following code

```
private static void showJSON(string testJson){

    Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(testJson);

    var dropdowns = response.OnlineFields.JsonFile;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dropdowns, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

This working fine. but the problem is my client sends me the following JSON through the API.

```
{  
   "Message":null,
   "Error":false,
   "VData":{  
      "RNumber":null,
      "BRNumber":"Session1"
   },
   "onlineFields":{  
      "CCode":"Web",
      "MNumber":"15478655",
      "Product":"100",
      "JsonFile":"      {  
         \"evaluation\":{  
            \"number\":[  
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"1000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are america\"
               },
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"2000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"100\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are japan\"
               },
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"3000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"1000\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are UK\"
               },
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"4000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are China\"
               }
            ]
         }
      } "     
   }
}
```

So how to escape this "`\`" characters and how to bind the client sent JSON to my model. In the client's JSON have inner JSON called JsonFile. This inner JSON consists with "`\`" and inner JSON consists within quotation `""`. So please give me a solution.

**Updated:**

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154043/how-do-i-convert-an-escaped-json-string-within-a-json-object/) post. I have tried this. but this makes me errors. So please give me a solution. In order to that post or any other way how to solve this

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
foreach (var response in (IEnumerable<dynamic>)obj.onlineFields)
{
    response.onlineFields.JsonFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject((string)response.onlineFields.JsonFile);
}
string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Comment: The value of `"JsonFile"` is embedded, double-serialized JSON, so you can use `EmbeddedLiteralConverter<JsonFile>` from [How do I convert an escaped JSON string within a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154630/3744182).

Comment: @dbc Hello sir, I'm new to c# and JSON, please give me sample code to solve my problem. please

Comment: Just deserialize to your `Response` type with `new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = { new EmbeddedLiteralConverter<JsonFile>() } }` as shown in https://dotnetfiddle.net/LuNdkf

Comment: @dbc Thank you sir, I again have a problem. please help me to solve it. 
this is my question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845381/how-to-escape-embedded-json-after-unescape