# How to escape embedded JSON after unescape

Tags: c#, json, json.net, escaping

When serializing with Json.NET, I need to escape embedded JSON after previously unescaping while deserializing. Which means I unescaped following JSON according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154043/how-do-i-convert-an-escaped-json-string-within-a-json-object/39154630#39154630) post.

Here is my JSON:

```
{  
   "Message":null,
   "Error":false,
   "VData":{  
      "RNumber":null,
      "BRNumber":"Session1"
   },
   "onlineFields":{  
      "CCode":"Web",
      "MNumber":"15478655",
      "Product":"100",
      "JsonFile":"      {  
         \"evaluation\":{  
            \"number\":[  
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"1000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are america\"
               },
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"2000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"100\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are japan\"
               },
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"3000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"1000\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are UK\"
               },
               {  
                  \"@paraID\":\"4000\",
                  \"@Value\":\"\",
                  \"@label\":\"We are China\"
               }
            ]
         }
      } "     
   }
}
```

After unescaping, I bind the above JSON to my model classes. And it works properly. to Bind JSON to a model I used following code.

```
private static void showJSON(string testJson){

    Response response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(testJson);

    var dropdowns = response.OnlineFields.JsonFile;

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dropdowns, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);

    Console.WriteLine(json);
}
```

After bind JSON to model, there has some logic to set values to JSON and returns unescaped JSON. which means it also returns unescaped `JsonFile`, I again need above JSON format (escaped embedded `JsonFile`) to send to the client API.

This is unescaped JSON format, I need convert this to above escaped JSON (escaped embedded `JsonFile`)

```
{  
   "Message":null,
   "Error":false,
   "VData":{  
      "RNumber":null,
      "BRNumber":"Session1"
   },
   "onlineFields":{  
      "CCode":"Web",
      "MNumber":"15478655",
      "Product":"100",
      "JsonFile":{  
         "evaluation":{  
            "number":[  
               {  
                  "@paraID":"1000",
                  "@Value":"",
                  "@label":"We are america"
               },
               {  
                  "@paraID":"2000",
                  "@Value":"100",
                  "@label":"We are japan"
               },
               {  
                  "@paraID":"3000",
                  "@Value":"1000",
                  "@label":"We are UK"
               },
               {  
                  "@paraID":"4000",
                  "@Value":"",
                  "@label":"We are China"
               }
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Previously I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802068/how-to-escape-especial-characters-in-json) for how to directly deserialize such embedded JSON into c# classes, but the answer there did not explain how to re-serialize in the same format.  I need to extend the answer from that previous question to writing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T>` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39154630/3744182) to *[How do I convert an escaped JSON string within a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39154043/3744182)* by overriding [`JsonConverter.WriteJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) and doing a **nested serialization**, then writing the resulting string literal, like so:

```
public class EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        using (new PushValue<bool>(true, () => Disabled, (canWrite) => Disabled = canWrite))
        {
            using (var sw = new StringWriter(writer.Culture))
            {
                // Copy relevant settings
                using (var nestedWriter = new JsonTextWriter(sw) 
                { 
                    DateFormatHandling = writer.DateFormatHandling,
                    DateFormatString = writer.DateFormatString,
                    DateTimeZoneHandling = writer.DateTimeZoneHandling,
                    StringEscapeHandling = writer.StringEscapeHandling,
                    FloatFormatHandling = writer.FloatFormatHandling,
                    Culture = writer.Culture,
                    // Remove if you don't want the escaped \r\n characters in the embedded JSON literal:
                    Formatting = writer.Formatting, 
                })
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(nestedWriter, value);
                }
                writer.WriteValue(sw.ToString());
            }
        }
    }

    [ThreadStatic]
    static bool disabled;

    // Disables the converter in a thread-safe manner.
    bool Disabled { get { return disabled; } set { disabled = value; } }

    public override bool CanWrite { get { return !Disabled; } }

    public override bool CanRead { get { return !Disabled; } }
    
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType);
        if (contract is JsonPrimitiveContract)
            throw new JsonSerializationException("Invalid type: " + objectType);
        if (existingValue == null)
            existingValue = contract.DefaultCreator();
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.String)
        {
            var json = (string)JToken.Load(reader);
            using (var subReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)))
            {
                // By populating a pre-allocated instance we avoid an infinite recursion in EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T>.ReadJson()
                // Re-use the existing serializer to preserve settings.
                serializer.Populate(subReader, existingValue);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            serializer.Populate(reader, existingValue);
        }
        return existingValue;
    }
}

struct PushValue<T> : IDisposable
{
    Action<T> setValue;
    T oldValue;

    public PushValue(T value, Func<T> getValue, Action<T> setValue)
    {
        if (getValue == null || setValue == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.setValue = setValue;
        this.oldValue = getValue();
        setValue(value);
    }

    #region IDisposable Members

    // By using a disposable struct we avoid the overhead of allocating and freeing an instance of a finalizable class.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (setValue != null)
            setValue(oldValue);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, add the converter to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) when deserializing and serializing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new EmbeddedLiteralConverter<JsonFile>() },
};

var response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Response>(testJson, settings);

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Or, you could apply the converter directly to your model using [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) like so:

```
public class OnlineFields
{
    public string CCode { get; set; }
    public string MNumber { get; set; }
    public string Product { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConverter(typeof(EmbeddedLiteralConverter<JsonFile>))]
    public JsonFile JsonFile { get; set; }
}
```

Notes:

- Your input JSON is, strictly speaking, **not well formed**.  The string value for the property `JsonFile` contains unescaped carriage return characters:

  ```
   "JsonFile":"      {  
      \"evaluation\":{  
         \"number\":[
  ```

  According to the [original JSON proposal](http://www.json.org/) as well as [JSON RFC 7159 Page 8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159#page-8) such control characters **must** be escaped:

  ```
   "{\r\n  \"evaluation\": {\r\n    \"number\": ..."
  ```

  To confirm this, you can upload your initial JSON to https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ which reports the following error:

  > Invalid JSON (RFC 4627): Error:Invalid characters found.[Code 18, Structure 39]

  As it turns out, Json.NET will read such invalid JSON without complaint, but will only write well-formed JSON by correctly escaping the carriage returns and line feeds inside the nested JSON literal.  Thus your re-serialized JSON will not look identical to the initial JSON.  It will, however, be well-formed, and should be consumable by any JSON parser.
- To prevent a stack overflow exception when serializing, `EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T>.WriteJson()` disables itself when called recursively by using the technique from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29720068/3744182) to *[JSON.Net throws StackOverflowException when using [JsonConvert()]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29719509/3744182)*.

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fbAoJ3).

Comment: Thank you, sir. :) you explain it very well :) Thanks again for your effort & kindly response :)