# JSON.Net How To Deserialize JSON within JSON

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization, nested-json

We are deserializing Json files with Newtonsoft JSON. How do you use the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>()` to deserialize a JSON, which in turn contains a JSON?

```
{
    "character": "Someone",
    "json": "{\"test\":true}"
}
```

We created a type for the nested JSON and decorated it with `JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverter))` or `JsonConverter(typeof(JsonConverter<PianoRhythmLessonData>))` but only got errors about missing constructor variants without parameter.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17038878/3952573 which I believe holds the answer to what you're looking for. Also have a look at how you get the best results for your questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Unfortunately not. They deserialize just MyData, which does not contain another JSON like we do

Comment: My Bad, could you provide an example of the PianoRhythmLessonData object.

Comment: `public class PianoRhythmLessonData
{
    public bool test;
}`

Comment: If you only need to deserialize your embedded double-serialized JSON see [How do I convert an escaped JSON string within a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39154043/3744182).  If you need to deserialize and re-serialize see [How to escape embedded JSON after unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51845381/3744182).

Comment: Both have answers that introduce an `EmbeddedLiteralConverter<T>` which you can apply to your `json` property like so `[JsonConverter(typeof(EmbeddedLiteralConverter<PianoRhythmLessonData>))] public PianoRhythmLessonData Json { get; set; }`