# How to convert a json within a json into object?

Tags: c#, json

So I got this guy

```
{
  "lng_x": "106.883368",
  "style": "{\"name\":\"TACTICAL\"}"
}
```

Which I wanted to make into this guy

```
public class Root
{
    public string lng_x { get; set; }
    public Style style { get; set; }
}

public class Style
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

But I got this instead

```
public class Root
{
    public string lng_x { get; set; }
    public string style { get; set; }
}
```

I know that the Json is supposed to be like this

```
{
  "lng_x": "106.883368",
  "style": 
  {
    "name": "TACTICAL"
  }
}
```

But I can't because it is already like that when I got it.

Is there any way so that I don't have to deserialize it again?

Comment: If you can't fix the document, you'll have to deserialize again. You can create a custom type converter for the `style` property

Comment: What parser are you using? JSON.NET? System.Text.Json?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm using Newtonsoft.Json / Json.NET. For now I am using a function to deserialize it again. I'm intrigued in what you say about converting it in the property, how do you do it?

Comment: I suggest this has to be fixed at source. who ever doing this, probably they are doing double serialization

Comment: @KrishnaVarma Yes, I don't know whoever it is that made it, it needs to be fixed. The problem is they are already gone and my higher ups just said to ignore it and just try to deserialize it by myself :).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape embedded JSON after unescape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51845381/how-to-escape-embedded-json-after-unescape) Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39154043/how-do-i-convert-an-escaped-json-string-within-a-json-object

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can't fix the JSON document you can [create a custom JSON type converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0) and apply it to the `style` property. And whoever created that document needs to fix their bug.

If you use System.Text.Json, a possible converter could be :

```
public class StyleStringJsonConverter : JsonConverter<Style>
{
    public override Style Read(
        ref Utf8JsonReader reader,
        Type typeToConvert,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Style>(reader.GetString()!);

    public override void Write(
        Utf8JsonWriter writer,
        Style style,
        JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
            writer.WriteStringValue(JsonSerializer.Serialize(style));
}
```

This can be applied through an attribute :

```
public class Root
{
    public string lng_x { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StyleStringJsonConverter))]
    public Style style { get; set; }
}
```

JSON.NET also has [custom converters](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm):

```
public class StyleStringConverter : JsonConverter<Style>
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Style value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        writer.WriteValue(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
    }

    public override Style ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Style existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        string s = (string)reader.Value;

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Style>(s);
    }

}
```

This can be applied using an attribute too:

```
public class Root
{
    public string lng_x { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(StyleStringJsonConverter))]
    public Style style { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok let me try it. And yes, whoever created the code in the first place needs to fix it. But it was already implemented in the system and there's ton of datas that already saved like that, and my higher ups just said to ignore it and just deserialize it by myself :'

Comment: It works! But I noticed that when I try to serialize it again it returns again into '"style": "{\"name\":\"TACTICAL\"}"'. Will it always be like that if the code is not fixed? Or can I change it into '"style": {"name": "TACTICAL"}'

Comment: Try `writer.WriteValue(value);` in that case. If you want to generate JSON in both formats you can also pass the converter as an option to the serializer instead of using an attribute

Comment: It returns with an error JsonWriterException: Unsupported type: HelperPlotting.Style.

Comment: In that case try `writer.WriteRaw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value))`. This writes the string as-is

Comment: Just tried it, it does not work. But if you change it to WriteRawValue it does work.

Comment: Sounds like you could create a completely generic form of this converter. I feel like there should be a dupe somewhere

Comment: @Charlieface yes, I've thought this from the start, but that's not what the question is about. Using `T` instead of `Style could cause confusion when people don't know about converters. Besides, the OP wants to generate valid JSON instead of a JSON string on serialization

Answer (score 0):

As stated before, the original creators should fix your the JSON file.
Meanwhile, you are stuck with it.

To make sure you don't dirty your own code

1. use Regex to make it a real JSON
2. Deserialize as normal

**Advantage**: When the JSON is changed to a correct form you have to remove the CleanJSON Method and your code will stay working.

**The Code**

```
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

function YourFunction(){
    //-- Get your JSON in string format (from API, file,...)
    string _jsonString = ... ;
    CleanJSON(_jsonString);
    YourModels.Root _correctStructure = (JsonSerializer.Deserialize<YourModels.Root>(_JSsonString);
}

function CleanJSON(string jsonString){
    //__ Probably you can group the regex
    string _regexPatternRoot = @"(\\"")(.*?)(\\)";
    string _regexReplacementRoot = @"""$2";
    string _regexPatternStyle = "\"({)\"(.*?)\"}\"";
    string _regexReplacementStyle = @"$1""$2""}";

    _JSsonString = Regex.Replace(_JSsonString, _regexPatternRoot, _regexReplacementRoot);
    _JSsonString = Regex.Replace(_JSsonString, _regexPatternStyle, _regexReplacementStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you don't need any custom converter. The problem is that your origional style property is a json string and you have to deserialize it. In this case I usually use a JsonConstructor

```
public class Root
{
    public string lng_x { get; set; }
    public Style style { get; set; }
    
    [JsonConstructor]
    public Root (string style)
    {
        this.style=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Style>(style);
    }
    public Root (){}
}
```

test

```
Root data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);

{
  "lng_x": "106.883368",
  "style": {
    "name": "TACTICAL"
  }
}
```

Comment: This is actually much simpler than using the custom converter. But I think I still gonna accept the Custom Converter answer because it also gives details on how to make a custom converter either on Json.Net or string.json. Thank you though !!